# Discord.js markdowns work on Iphone and computer, not android

Tags: discord, discord.js, markdown

So I am creating a table for a discord bot and I have the code set up to bold and quote for headlines. It seems the code works for IPhones and computers, my android though doesn't like to do both at once. I did some testing on discord and know that I can combine bold with italicize. How would I combine quote with bold though?

```
embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                   .setColor('RANDOM')
                   .setTitle('Allioni')
                   .setThumbnail('https://rerollcdn.com/SDSGC/portraits/portrait_20.png')
                   .setDescription('Beard of the Mountain Cat')
                   .addFields(
                                {name: '**> Base Stats **', value: '**Attack:**\n170\n**Defense:**'+
                                       '\n120\n**HP:**\n2000'},
                                {name: '**> Red Demon **', value: 'Not Recommended'},
                                {name: '**> Grey Demon **', value: 'Attack, Defense'},
                                {name: '**> Crimson Demon **', value: 'Not Recommended'},
                                {name: '**> Gear **', value: 'Attack, Defense'},
                                {name: '**> Subrolls **', value:'Attack, Defense, HP'}
                             )
```

Whats happening on my phone:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PUy9.jpg)

What I want to happen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB2Fb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
 embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                   .setColor('RANDOM')
                   .setTitle('Allioni')
                   .setThumbnail('https://rerollcdn.com/SDSGC/portraits/portrait_20.png')
                   .setDescription('Beard of the Mountain Cat')
                   .addFields(
                                {name: '** Base Stats **', value: '**Attack:**\n170\n**Defense:**'+
                                       '\n120\n**HP:**\n2000'},
                                {name: '> **Red Demon **', value: 'Not Recommended'},
                                {name: '> **Grey Demon **', value: 'Attack, Defense'},
                                {name: '> **Crimson Demon **', value: 'Not Recommended'},
                                {name: '> **Gear **', value: 'Attack, Defense'},
                                {name: '> **Subrolls **', value:'Attack, Defense, HP'}
                             )
```

Don't bold the ">"

Comment: Thank you! I thought I tested that case earlier today.